# How to call the form fields in a route file in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

Give me an  idea to call the form fields and controller in the route file and store them into the WHMCS i.e., add the client details to WHMCS. Find below the Route along with the form fields.

```
Route::get('/create', function () {
    $users = Whmcs::AddClient([
        'firstname' => Input::get('firstname'),
        'lastname' => Input::get('lastname'),
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'address1' => Input::get('address1'),
        'city' => Input::get('city'),
        'state' => Input::get('state'),
        'postcode' => Input::get('postcode'),
        'country' => Input::get('country'),
        'phonenumber' => Input::get('phonenumber'),
        'password2' => Input::get('password2'),
        'responsetype' => 'json',    
    ]);
    return $users;
});
```

Find below the controller code

```
class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function insertform(){
        return view('clientlayout.main.signup');
    } 

    public function create(){
        $firstname = trim(htmlentities($_POST["firstname"]));
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you clearly explain your question. Because its make someone to help you easily

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following may help point you in the right direction:
Adapt to your requirements and place inside your controller.

```
public function createUser($request)
{
    //Create user
    $newUser = new User;
    $newUser->username = $request->username;
    $newUser->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $newUser->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $newUser->email = $request->email;
    $newUser->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $newUser->last_login_at = Carbon::now();

    $newUser->save();
    //Manually assign the role_id so no escalating privileges.
    $newUser->assignRole('user');

    return $newUser;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> First of all you have to follow MVC method in laravel
>
> **Route**

```
 Route::match(['get','post'],'/create', 'ControllerName@functionname');
```

> **controller**

```
    public function create(Request $request){
        $id = modelname::modelfunctionname($request->Input());
            print "<pre>";
            print_r ($request->input());
            print "</pre>"; exit;   
    }
```

**$request->input() you will get the form fields**

> **In Your model**

```
public static function modelfunctionname($input){
    $create = DB::table('admins')->insertGetId(array(
      'firstname' => $input['firstname'],
      'lastname' => $input['lastname']
        like this Do it for remaining field
    ));
    return $create;
}
```